# Миграция Yii could not find driver

Tags: миграция, openserver, yii

Написали миграцию на Yii - на двух компьютерах где стоит XAMPP миграция прошла успешно. Но на сервере OpenServer, у меня на локалке, при миграции (провожу из NetBeans-а) выходит ошабка:

> exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

Настройки в **console.php** такие же как на **main.php**:

```
'components'=>array(
        'db'=>array
        (
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

В чем может быть ошибка, и как можно запустить миграцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам покопался, и порылся по интернету, вот несколько из методов решения:

1. В первую очередь необходимо **проверить настройки в php.ini**, на включенных `php_mysql`,`php_pdo_mysql`, проверить адрес подключаемых Ext (в том числе можно попробовать указать полные пути; если в пути встречаются пробелы, то записать в двойных кавычках)
2. Также в php.ini: **PDO support** => enabled
3. Настройки подключения в **console.php** и **main.php** должны быть одинаковые
4. При консольном варианте работы, NetBeans может не знать полных путей к драйверам у OpenServer. Варианты решений: **запустить NetBeans после запуска сервера**; запустить NetBeans через сам OpenServer, чтобы он скушал все настройки и каталоги.

У меня миграцию так и не удалось запустить, и чтобы не терять время, провел миграцию в ручном режиме.

Answer (score 4):

Не установлено расширение для работы с MySQL  в PHP.

Например в Ubuntu его можно установить командой:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: 1) сайт прекрасно подключается к базе данных

2) через NetBeans к базе тоже идет подключение (т.е. он может видеть структуру таблиц)

Comment: Какая у вас связка PHP+веб-сервер?

Comment: @artkil

веб-сервер - OpenServer: **Apache-2.2.22**, **PHP-5.4.5**, **MySQL-5.1.63**

подозреваю, что в php.ini что-то отключено

Comment: Получается что так.

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло это http://tarlyun.com/blog/2012/08/18/nastraivaem-openserver-dlya-raboty-s-laravel/

Comment: нормально. Но к сожалению я уже перешел на XAMPP и настроил все там...

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже искал ответ на этот вопрос, но все оказалось банально просто, поскольку в OpenServer своя Console. Нужно через неё делать миграцию и всё будет хорошо.